# Get last day of a given quarter and Year in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, select

I have 2 variables year and quarter that I get from the view. I have to pass these values to get the last date of that particular Quarter and Year. Is there a way to do that in SQL?

For example:

```
select (QuarterEndDate) where Year = @year and Quarter = @quarter
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `datefromparts()` and `eomonth()`:

```
select eomonth(datefromparts(@year, 3 * @quarter, 1))
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=47557708495e2dd3a408e8bab0eef375)**:

```
declare @year int;
declare @quarter int;

set @year = 2020;
set @quarter = 3;

select eomonth(datefromparts(@year, 3 * @quarter, 1)) last_quarter_day
GO
```

```
| last_quarter_day |
| :--------------- |
| 2020-09-30       |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, should give you the last date of the quarter.

first option: `qq` is your quarter number.

```
dateadd(qq, DateDiff(qq, 0, @Date), -1)
```

second option:

```
dateadd(D,-1,dateadd(M, 3*qq+3, CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(5),@year)+'-1-1')))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is giving me the last day of next quarter. Suppose I pass @Quarter(number) as 1 and @year as 2020, it is showing 30-06-2020. It should have shown 31-03-2020. Please help.

Comment: @Neeta put your quarter no. in `qq` like 1, 2, 3 in above formula and see if you are getting your expected result or not. Also added one more option.

Comment: Even if I put the quarter in qq, it is showing the last day of next quarter. Thank you so much.